# Will fight for the

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the exact meaning of the sentence in bold? It is from the book “Persian Gulf Command” by Ashley Jackson, p. 179. It is a report about the Iranian attitude about the Allied forces who occupied Iran in 1941. Who is the subject of the sentence in bold? Why does not have it a mentioned subject?

> Regarding the sentiments of Iranian officers in the Kermanshah and Hamadan regions, the consul reported:
>
> > General attitude summed up as We hate all foreign troops – be it English, Russian or even German. We like them as individuals apart from the Russians whom we all loathe. **Will fight for the British against Russians anytime but against Germans can’t yet say.** They doubted that the British would help them get the Russians out of Azerbaijan.

Thanks a million.

Comment: The omitted subject is 'we' matching the other two sentences. In this case the consul is expressing the view of the Iranian officers in the areas mentioned so the sentences can be considered as directly reported speech even though there are no quotation marks and none of the officers put their views in those exact words. The views are certainly _not_ those of the consul. The style is slightly odd for an official report since it is conversational  rather than formal, in conversational speech it would be more recognisable.

Comment: It is the Iranian officers. They say "We hate all" and "We like them." They will fight for the British.